# SQL извлечь названия неполных столбцов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Возникло интересное задание. В таблице может быть неопределенное количество столбцов. Каждый столбец соответствует одной дате, а так же есть всего 4 ячейки. Нужно вывести названия всех незаполненных до конца столбцов. БД - PostgreSQL, если вдруг играет роль. Буду рад услышать ваши варианты!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Я создаю чат-бота, в котором люди могут записываться на сеансы у одного врача. У этого врача не постоянный график, т.е. нет четкого 2/2 или 3/3. Соответственно для записи пользователю нужно выбрать дату, в которую он придет. Я придумал такую схему: врач пишет чат-боту дни, в которые он может принять клиентов, после чего создается запрос, в котором добавляются новые столбцы в БД, в названии которых заключена дата. Ну и каждая строка рассчитана на одного человека, т.е. запись.

Comment: Как соотносится *может быть неопределенное количество столбцов* с *есть всего 4 ячейки*? Что значит *незаполненных до конца столбцов*, особенно в контексте, что это тип ДАТА?

Comment: @SwaD добавил пример таблицы. Может быть неправильно сформулировал. В данном примере на мой запрос должно будет вывестись 11 августа и 15 августа, т.к. 10 августа полностью заполнено

Comment: А что такое четыре ячейки? Может, четыре строки?

Comment: Вообще, возникает подозрение, что вы решаете какую-то задачу, придумали вот такой извращённый способ организации данных, а теперь не знаете, как его обработать. Если нужна помощь, до давайте начнём с исходной задачи.

Comment: @rotabor да, 4 строки. И хорошо чуть позже в правки добавлю всю суть задачи

Comment: @rotabor все, внес правки, просмотрите исходную задачу, пожалуйста.

Comment: Одной даты мало. Наверняка у врача может быть разное число часов/слотов в разные даты.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, конечно. Я писал, что столбцов может быть неопределенное количество(столбцы=даты). А так же с ним самим обговаривалось, что максимум в день он принимает четверых клиентов, поэтому всего четыре строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

1. Врач пишет в бот дату и кол-во людей, которые он может принять в этот день. Это записывается в таблицу Doctor(OpenDate,NumberOfPeople).
2. Для регистрации пациентов используется другая таблица Patients(AppointmentDate,PatientName).
3. Пациенты записываются на даты:

```
SELECT OpenDate
FROM (
    SELECT T2.OpenDate, Count(T1.PatientName) AS COP,MIN(T2.NumberOfPeople) AS NOP
    FROM Doctor AS T2 LEFT JOIN Patients AS T1 ON T2.OpenDate = T1.AppointmentDate
    GROUP BY T2.OpenDate
)
WHERE COP<NOP
```

T1 и T2 - это псевдонимы для таблиц или имена для результатов запросов. T1 - псевдоним для таблицы Patients, T2 - для для таблицы Doctor. Псевдонимы используются вместо имён таблиц либо как имена запросов.

Псевдонимы для таблиц необязательны, но используются для сокращения текста запроса, а псевдонимы для результатов запросов нужны чтобы просто иметь возможность к ним как-то обращаться.

Почитайте литературу по SQL.

Как работает этот запрос?

Подзапрос

```
SELECT T2.OpenDate, Count(T1.PatientName) AS COP,MIN(T2.NumberOfPeople) AS NOP
FROM Doctor AS T2 LEFT JOIN Patients AS T1 ON T2.OpenDate = T1.AppointmentDate
GROUP BY T2.OpenDate
```

объединяет таблицы по дате, причём из таблицы Doctor выбираются все имеющиеся даты и по ним происходит группировка результатов. Для каждой даты подсчитывается количество записавшихся пациентов и выводится кол-во пациентов, которых готов принять доктор.

А верхний запрос по результатам подзапроса выводит даты, где кол-во записавшихся пациентов меньше, чем кол-во пациентов, которых готов принять доктор.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Хотел бы еще разобраться в самом запросе, могли бы вы его детальнее описать? Или хотя бы объяснить что такое Т1 и Т2?

Comment: Еще раз благодарю за полное объяснение. Стало в разы понятнее